# My domain is returning a 500 error, where can I find an error log, or how can I resolve this?

Tags: dns, error-log

I'm currently getting a 500 error (apparently) on a url of mine, even though I'm sure I've configured it correctly. Where can I find my error log on Linux?

Willing to provide more details if you need...

Comment: If anything this might belong on server fault, but not superuser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- RHEL / Red Hat / CentOS / Fedora
  Linux Apache error file location -
  **/var/log/httpd/error_log**
- Debian / Ubuntu Linux Apache error
  log file location -
  **/var/log/apache2/error.log**
- FreeBSD Apache error log file
  location - **/var/log/httpd-error.log**

Comment: I'm using CentOS, and I can't find /httpd, nor apache2 not http-error.log. All there is (folder wise) is bandwidth, sa and dcpumon o_O.

Comment: Shared host perhaps? Ask your provider.. I'm running CentOS and my log files are in that dir. Sorry I'm unable to help.

Comment: It could be anything, even a missing library. I received a 500 error yesterday, it was the mod_rewrite module. So yeah.. @Sam - try searching for the file/folder using *locate*. i.e. *locate error* or *locate log*

Answer (score 0):

Check out /var/log/apache2.

This should contain the logs you are looking for.

Hope that helps!

Nick 
nickgs.com

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have this folder o_O